# rootRef.current.contains is not a function on react-transition-group Transition Component on latest React and MUI v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, transition, react-transition-group

I am migrating a project from Material-UI 4 to MUI v5, where I also upgraded react to v18. We are using `Transition` from `react-transition-group` on one of our components, inside of a Modal. I get a `rootRef.current.contains is not a function` error on a `TrapFocus` component. I am not using a TrapFocus component.

Here is my codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-pare-gx08dc?file=/demo.js:0-847

```
import React from "react";
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group";
class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ open: true });
          }}
        >
          Click Me
        </button>
        <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={() => {
            this.setState({ open: false });
          }}
        >
          <Transition
            in={open}
            timeout={{
              enter: 0,
              exit: 500
            }}
          >
            <div>Hello</div>
          </Transition>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

My environment is as follows:

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
"@mui/material": "^5.9.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-transition-group": "^4.4.2"
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, turns out I have to wrap the Transition in a div. but idk why that fixes this

Comment: Hey @sshakya, I believe the modal transitions are still not being replaced by react-transition-group transitions? Thoughts.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using [`react-zoom-pan-pinch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) and React fragment works for me too, to keep the DOM clean

Comment: For future readers (and AIs), my use case: `TransformWrapper` of `react-zoom-pan-pinch` **directly** inside a `Modal` component of mui (material-ui).